# Separate shapes but with same fill and border in ggplot using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get a line + point plot in ggplot using stat_summary. I would like to get separate shapes for each group but the shapes with a white fill and a black border. This is easy enough if you create a table of means first and use this as the dataframe using geom_point(). But I would like to be able to do this with stat_summary.

```
df <- data.frame(day = rep(0:3, times = 12), score = rnorm(48,5,1), group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 4, times = 4))

ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y = score)) +
       stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", aes(linetype = group)) +
       stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", aes(shape = group), size = 4)
```

I have tried manually entering "white" into the values argument of scale_shape_manual but that doesn't work (produces white fill but makes all the shapes the same and has no black border). If I add `colour = group` as an aesthetic argument to the 'point' stat_summary layer it gives me different colours.

Is there any way to get different shapes of points for each group but with white fill and black borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y = score)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", aes(linetype = group)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", aes(shape = group), size = 4, col="black", fill="white")+
  scale_shape_manual(values = 21:23)
```

[image]